# SystemError: returned NULL without setting an error in MDKivy app

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Does anyone know how to solve this question? I just added a Chinese font to my Kivy app, but it throws up an error, then I comment those codes:

```
#from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
#LabelBase.register(name='WenQuanYi Micro Hei', fn_regular='/usr/share/fonts/truetype/wqy/wqy-microhei.ttc')
```

It still throws up the same error. Hummm...

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/user002/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 240, in create_handler
     return eval(value, idmap), bound_list
   File "/home/user002/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/data/style.kv", line 117, in <module>
     xy: self.pos
 SystemError: <cyfunction ObservableReferenceList.__setslice__ at 0x7f99e10450> returned NULL without setting an error
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/user002/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 922, in _build_canvas
     value, _ = create_handler(
   File "/home/user002/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 243, in create_handler
     raise BuilderException(rule.ctx, rule.line,
 kivy.lang.builder.BuilderException: Parser: File "/home/user002/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/data/style.kv", line 117:
 ...
     115:        PushMatrix
     116:        Translate:
 >>  117:            xy: self.pos
     118:    canvas.after:
     119:        PopMatrix
 ...
 SystemError: <cyfunction ObservableReferenceList.__setslice__ at 0x7f99e10450> returned NULL without setting an error
   File "/home/user002/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 240, in create_handler
     return eval(value, idmap), bound_list
   File "/home/user002/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/data/style.kv", line 117, in <module>
     xy: self.pos
 
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/user002/Digital_decor_2.0/digital_decor_app4.py", line 1075, in <module>
     App().run()
   File "/home/user002/Digital_decor_2.0/digital_decor_app4.py", line 949, in __init__
     self.filemanager = MDFileManager(select_path=self.select_path,exit_manager=self.exit_manager,preview=True)
   File "/home/user002/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivymd/uix/filemanager/filemanager.py", line 451, in __init__
     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/home/user002/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivymd/uix/behaviors/declarative_behavior.py", line 311, in __init__
     super().__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/home/user002/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/uix/relativelayout.py", line 274, in __init__
     super(RelativeLayout, self).__init__(**kw)
   File "/home/user002/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/uix/floatlayout.py", line 65, in __init__
     super(FloatLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/home/user002/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/uix/layout.py", line 76, in __init__
     super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/home/user002/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 366, in __init__
     self.apply_class_lang_rules(
   File "/home/user002/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 470, in apply_class_lang_rules
     Builder.apply(
   File "/home/user002/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 540, in apply
     self._apply_rule(
   File "/home/user002/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 595, in _apply_rule
     self._build_canvas(widget.canvas.before, widget,
   File "/home/user002/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 928, in _build_canvas
     raise BuilderException(
 kivy.lang.builder.BuilderException: Parser: File "/home/user002/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/data/style.kv", line 117:
 ...
     115:        PushMatrix
     116:        Translate:
 >>  117:            xy: self.pos
     118:    canvas.after:
     119:        PopMatrix
 ...
 BuilderException: Parser: File "/home/user002/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/data/style.kv", line 117:
 ...
     115:        PushMatrix
     116:        Translate:
 >>  117:            xy: self.pos
     118:    canvas.after:
     119:        PopMatrix
 ...
 SystemError: <cyfunction ObservableReferenceList.__setslice__ at 0x7f99e10450> returned NULL without setting an error
   File "/home/user002/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 240, in create_handler
     return eval(value, idmap), bound_list
   File "/home/user002/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/data/style.kv", line 117, in <module>
     xy: self.pos
 
   File "/home/user002/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 922, in _build_canvas
     value, _ = create_handler(
   File "/home/user002/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 243, in create_handler
     raise BuilderException(rule.ctx, rule.line,
```

I checked the /../../style.kv, and tried to comment the 117 line:

```
xy: self.pos
```

But it doesn't work. It still reports the system error.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Chinese version for Raspiberry again, and select zh_CN.GB2312，zh_CN.GB18030，zh_GBK，zh_CN.UTF-8, all of them and then reboot the system. Then solve this SystemError. As before, I just only selected the zh_CN.UTF-8, so it reports me the error.